# Django auth app - only one argument being given to login(), which takes two arguments

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-login

I'm working in Django for the first time and so far it's been hopping from error to error, which is really forcing me to pay attention to what I'm doing. However there's this issue which has been bugging me quite a bit.

I'm getting the following error in my browser:

```
TypeError at /login/
login() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
login() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

When I take a look at the code in my **views.py** that takes care of my authenticate() and login() functions, I've got the following code:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def login_user(request):
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get['username']
        password = request.POST.get['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)            
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
    return render_to_response('undercovercoders/index.html', {'state':state, 'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I was using the official docs to create the if/else loop up there, but why is is not being defined? Is it because the authenticate() is returning nothing? Shouldn't that mean the website returns the error state? Thank you so much for helping, let me know if there's anything I can add!

**Edit**

My *urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/$','portal.views.index'),
    (r'^$','portal.views.index'), 

 # Login / logout.

(r'^registration/$', 'portal.views.registration'),
(r'^login/$', 'portal.views.login'),
(r'^dashboard/$', 'portal.views.dashboard'),
(r'^team/$', 'portal.views.team'),
(r'^about/$', 'portal.views.about'),
(r'^parents/$', 'portal.views.parents'),
(r'^legal/$', 'portal.views.legal'),
(r'^index/$', 'portal.views.index'),
```

Comment: Can you post your urls.py?

Comment: @sazpaz yes i just added it to my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how you have:

```
(r'^login/$', 'portal.views.login'),
```

But your view is called `login_user`.

Replace the line above with

```
(r'^login/$', 'portal.views.login_user'),
```

Your `/login/` url was actually calling the `django.auth.login` method instead of your view.

Comment: Right. So I fixed that line, and it now is displaying another error: `'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: FIXED! NEVER MIND! I had get[...] instead of get(...) in my first if loop beautiful thank you so much for helping